# Funnel Chart In Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am creating a dashboard in Apache Superset. I want to create a funnel representation of my overall data. I didn't find any funnel charts. Is it possible to add user defined visualizations on superset. If yes, what is the method to do so. If no, what are its alternative (I am aware of bar charts)

I have followed this https://shopup.me/blog/beginners-guide-set-superset-opensource-bi-platform-ec2-aws-instance/ documentation to install superset on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

you can definitely create your own custom visualizations (but I will warn you that adding custom viz plugins isn't a mature feature set yet). Here are some helpful links:

- https://preset.io/blog/2020-07-02-hello-world/
- https://medium.com/nmc-techblog/apache-superset-manage-custom-viz-plugins-in-production-9fde1a708e55

I will say that there are many ways to visualize funnels, which I talk about in this blog post: https://preset.io/blog/2020-07-14-funnels/